# OpenCV resize() TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Here is the code that I am running

```
import cv2
import glob
for image in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
img=cv2.imread(image,1)
rs=img.resize(img, int(img.shape[0]/2),int(img.shape[1]/2))
cv2.imshow(img)
cv2.waitKey(2000)
cv2.destoryAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite("Resized"+img,rs)
```

But I am getting the following error on resize method

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

even if I specify I still get this error

```
rs=img.resize(img, 300,500)
```

Why is this happening? thanks for your help on this.

Sid

Comment: It's happening because instead of `cv2.resize`, you're invoking the `resize` member of image (i.e.`numpy.ndarray.resize`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `cv2.resize(img, (300,500))` instead of `img.resize(img, 300,500)`.